# Retrieving data as lowercase from cakephp find method with list

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want retrieve data as lowercase list from cakephp using `find` method

Normally I retrieve data by using this code

```
$this->model->find('list', array('fields' => array('Area.id', 'Area.name'), 'recursive' => -1));
```

and my output is

```
array(
   '1' => 'Dhaka'
   '2' => 'New Yourk'
   '3' => 'Japan'
)
```

But I want to get output like this

```
array(
   '1' => 'dhaka'
   '2' => 'new yourk'
   '3' => 'japan'
)
```

to get this output I try this code

```
$this->model->find('list', array('fields' => array('Area.id', 'LOWER(Area.name)'), 'recursive' => -1));
```

But it gives me an array.

```
array(
   '1' => 
   '2' => 
   '3' => 
)
```

I know I can do this job with a loop. But I don't want to use loop here.

any solutions without loop?

Comment: Hi, I´d try LOWER(\'Area.name\') instead....

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a $virtualFields variable in Model. Set it like as below:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'title' => "LOWER(Area.name)"
    );
```

And In your find query in controller. PLease change

```
$this->Area->find("all", array("fields" => array("Area.id", "Area.title")));
```

It will work..

Comment: @Vineet - You can also use `$this->Area->virtualFields = array(
        'title' => "LOWER(Area.name)"
    ); `, so that it is not there when not needed.